# Make Dynamic HTML Drop Down Link To Choice Page

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Zw3M/1/

```
var data = [ // The data
    ['ten', ['eleven','twelve']],
    ['twenty', ['twentyone', 'twentytwo']]
];

$a = $('#a'); // The dropdowns
$b = $('#b');

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var first = data[i][0];
    $a.append($("<option>"). // Add options
       attr("value",first).
       data("sel", i).
       text(first));
}

$a.change(function() {
    var index = $(this).children('option:selected').data('sel');
    var second = data[index][1]; // The second-choice data

    $b.html(''); // Clear existing options in second dropdown

    for(var j = 0; j < second.length; j++) {
        $b.append($("<option>"). // Add options
           attr("value",second[j]).
           data("sel", j).
           text(second[j]));
    }
}).change(); // Trigger once to add options at load of first choice
```

No, i didn't write it.

What I'm trying to do is create a sort of navigation where the user can pick a brand, pick a specific product to that brand (this list will be generated after brand is picked) and then when they pick the specific item in the 2nd dropdown link to that page.

So how do I create a link for each option in the final drop down?

Thanks for helping smarter people

Comment: after selecting first option, you have to make AJAX request.

Comment: @DangerD do you mean `how do I create a link for each option in the final drop down` by this is that on selection in 2nd dropdown page should go to some other page?

Comment: yes each option in the final drop down should link to a different page

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially looking for an auto-submitting form. Here's a basic version, but you could use AJAX to build a custom URL or whatever - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Zw3M/862/).

```
<!--HTML-->
<form action="somepage">
    <select id=a name="a"></select>
    <select id=b name="b"></select>
</form>

...
// Javascript
$b.change(function(){
    $b.closest('form').submit();
});
```